# DATABASE ERROR: CONNECTION FAILED on Roundcube

Tags: phpmyadmin, roundcube

I am non techy person. I have already database named Roundcube on PHPmyadmin, I am unable to get code to paste  localhost -->roundcube (database) --> SQL. Is there anyone who can provide me the code to run my roundcube successfully.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what your problem is or what you're trying to accomplish. The title and message body of this post seem to me to be talking about two different problems. If you're having trouble connecting to Roundcube, please copy and paste the full error message. If you're trying to get SQL from phpMyAdmin in to Roundcube, you'll have to provide some more information about that process and what exactly is failing along the way.

Comment: I have upgraded my WP PHP version, which was hosted on Contabo VPS, from that time, I am getting an issue. Somewhere I have read the article about fixing it but I am Failed. Solution i haI have already a database named Roundcube on PHPmyadmin, I am unable to get code to paste localhost -->roundcube (database) --> SQL. Is there anyone who can provide me the code to run my Roundcube successfully? You can view the screenshot-https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NukxejZSepFbfWzC8-H24cVRH0tTaCG-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not able to load your picture due to a permission problem, could you double-check that? What code is it that you are trying to paste?